# How to access UITabBarBackgroundView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have been trying to make transparent tabBar background, but something, called UITabBarBackgroundView, is present and has white background.
How can i access it?

[image]

Comment: you can simply use a transparent image and use to set the background view of tabbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct way of doing this. You will have to create an illusion of transparency here. One way to do this is to set an image in tab bar. You can add following category on `UITabBarController` and call it

```
- (void) setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image 
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:imageView];
    [self.view setOpaque:NO];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

Another way (image way only :)):

```
UIImage *tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBarBackground.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:127.0/255.0 green:186.0/255.0 blue:235.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBarItemSelected.png"]];
```